# Color box with multiple lines and underlined text (within a paragraph)

Tags: underline, colorbox

In a paragraph, I want to highlight some part of the text (not the whole paragraph!) with a colorbox and also underline the text within that colorbox. This would be the result that I am looking for:

[image]

I can do the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%%%%%
% Colorboxed and underlined text (one line)
\newcommand{\tp}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{\setulcolor{blue}\ul{#1}}}

\begin{document}
This is the beginning of the paragraph, and now I am interested in 
\tp{highlighting a couple of lines of this paragraph with both underlined text
and a colorbox}. If I want to highlight just a couple of words in the same line,
 \tp{I can use this}. But it does not work when interested in highlighting 
multiple lines, because the line does not break.
\end{document}
```

But the (multiple line) highlighted text does not linebreak at the end of the page!! So I tried the following instead:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color,soul} % Para colored underlined
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

%%%%
%  Colorboxed and underlined text (one line)
\newcommand{\tp}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \setulcolor{blue}
    \sethlcolor{yellow}
    \hl{\ul{#1}}
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
This is the beginning of the paragraph, and now I am interested in 
\tp{highlighting a couple of lines of this paragraph with both underlined text 
and a colorbox}. Here my paragraph ends.
\end{document}
```

but it does not work... some error happens. Would you know what I should do to have underlined text within a colorbox in the middle of a paragraph?

I hope my problem is clear enough... :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please -- as usual here -- make your code snippets be compilable? Then we have not to huess what you are doing ...

Comment: Thanks for your remark, Mensch! And sorry for not being that precise the first time... :-/

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Run with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor}
\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul}
\newcommand\ulcol[2][black!15]{\highLight[#1]{\ul{#2}}}
\begin{document}
    Lots of stuff is \ulcol{important enough to be highlighted,
    but only few things are dangerous enough to deserve}
    \ulcol[red]{red highlighting.
    Let's go back to traditional highlighting}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The soul manual (§ 22) says that soul commands must not be nested. Though, the suggested solution to use a box, does not help you, because

> ,,It will, of course, not get broken then.''

Besides, only if you intend to express two different things at the same time by underlining as well as highlighting the same text, you should choose for just one of the means. It makes more sense, and it looks better to the reader.